# Why does my faucet handle swivel at the wrong joint?

Tags: bathroom, faucet

I have a 2 handle Moen faucet.

The right side faucet Handle does not Swivel for choosing hot water line.
In fact, the entire handle where it meets the base swivels instead of just top handle like it should and does on the left handle.

I applied a high quality silicone lubricant on handle, but when I try to open up water line, the entire handle including base swivels instead of just the top.

[image]

Comment: I'm wondering where the question is.

Comment: Usually, in the western hemisphere, the hot water is on the left. Can you stick your head in the cabinet, use a flashlight, and then have someone wiggle the handle to see if there is nut you can tighten ?

Comment: I thought of the basic rules of plumbing also hot on left cold on right and S4!t flows down hill but was not sure if that was the same for the rest of the world.+ Atul are we guessing correctly at your question or lack there of?

Comment: Sorry left is for hot water. 
If you think of the handles as inverted L, hot line only the top swivel moves, but for right side the entire handle ( the inverted L) moves...does my question make sense?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the faucet was not properly assembled if you are asking how to fix it there are normally nuts on each handle holding them in place you will probably need to remove the assembly and tighten the nut so the entire valve doesn’t rotate.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that some internal component to the handle is missing or has come loose. Go to the moen web site and locate the parts explosion diagram for the specific model faucet handle to see what's supposed to be in there. Perhaps you are missing a set screw? You could then get parts from Moen f it is under warranty or get a complete faucet replacement from where it was purchased (if you know this).

The nuts underneath only hold the faucet tight  to the countertop.